# Writing Midi Files in Java

Tags: java, midi

I have a project where I want to write midi files. Nothing too complicated as far as the notes go -- no pitch bends, no key signature, set tempo etc. Using just standard a,b,c notes. For example, I want to write 3 notes a,b,c as 16th notes.

This may not be an easy task.

But if not are there some good sites for midi structure?

Should also mention I do not want to use javax.sound.midi. I want to write the midi as a "string" then save it out.

Comment: It's trivial; it's a very well-documented file format. What specifically are you having issues with?

Comment: I do not know where to begin specifically.

Comment: *"I do not want to use javax.sound.midi"*  Why not?

Comment: More for learning experience. I have found some good link to midi specifications. Reading up on it.

Comment: Found what I needed. http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/midi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Java implementation of MIDI up on Google Code if you want to browse/use it:

http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

Answer (score 4):

I'm using http://www.jfugue.org for my MIDI-generating app http://github.com/okohll/TextSound. Example:

```
Player player = new Player();
File file = new File("out.mid")
String s = "A B C D E F G";
player.saveMidi(s, file);
player.play(s);
```